# UIPageControl placed manually goes off screen on rotation event

Tags: swift, rotation, uipageviewcontroller, landscape, uipagecontrol

UIPageControl that was placed *programatically in the view* vanishes (off screen?) when device is rotated.

The app I’m currently working on has a UIPageViewController that has 3 ViewControllers.

I’m scrolling through these fine. No problems - either in portrait OR landscape.

I added a UIPageControl to the UIPageViewController, in code - not in the Storyboard, and as such, in portrait mode, I have a nice sequence of dots that show the scroll position through my paged ViewControllers.

That all works great.

EXCEPT, when I rotate into landscape.

```swift
private func configurePageControl()
{
    self.pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 90, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)
}
```

When in landscape the UIPageViewController and the 3 ViewControllers work perfectly; scrolling and showing content and are interactive.

However the UIPageControl indicator as ‘vanished’.

Now, I will preface this with the fact that my UIPageViewController is part of a larger UITabBarViewController project, and as such at the bottom of the screen is a Tab Bar.

But when in portrait, I specifically positioned the UIPageControl (in code) to be ‘above’ that tab bar, and it is, and it displays, but it’s totally gone in landscape.

NB: That code is in the UIPageViewController where nothing else but the handling of the 3 separate view controllers lives.

Thanks.

Comment: "I added a UIPageControl to the UIPageViewController" UIPageViewController includes a UIPageControl already, so why did you add another one?

Comment: Because I followed his instructions in this video:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1qdWElN3iAhVy8eAKHTRGAzEQtwIwAHoECCcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRVAtqQ8CyKM&usg=AOvVaw1TLqLSyf9nNZn138vRSeyv